# physicsBody collision with another physicsBody

Tags: xcode, swift, sprite-kit

Okay, so I have a really specific problem and I hope I can help you. I will attach an image to clarify what I'm talking about.

[image: clarification]

`redball.physicsBody` is spawning above `boss.physicsBody` - falling (through) the boss. Colliding with `whitebar.physicsBody` - bouncing back up and once again colliding with `boss.physicsBody`. THIS time, i want to fire an event that notices when the ball is bouncing back up and hitting the boss.

Currently. Boss & Ball shares the same collisionBitMask, so that they can pass through each other. When the ball collides with the bar, I'm trying to add `ball.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.boss.rawValue` to the ball. So that i can notice the collision on the way back up between ball & boss. However this does not seem to work.

Does anyone have a solution to this weird problem? Super thankful for some help.

Sidenote: If someone can figure out a clever title, let me know and ill edit it!

EDIT: Adding code

```
enum PhysicsCategory : UInt32 {
  case bar = 1
  case ball = 2
  case boss = 4
  case noCollision = 8
}

class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

var score = Int()
var background = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "background.png")
var bar = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bar.png")
var boss1 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "boss1.png")

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    self.scene?.size = CGSize(width: 640, height:1136)
    physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self

    background.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width / 2, y: self.frame.height / 2)
    background.zPosition = -20
    self.addChild(background)

    bar.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width / 2, y: self.frame.height / 8)
    bar.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSize(width: bar.size.width, height: bar.size.height))
    bar.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.bar.rawValue
    bar.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.ball.rawValue
    bar.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.bar.rawValue
    bar.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    bar.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
    self.addChild(bar)

    boss1.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width, y: self.frame.height - boss1.size.height / 2)
    boss1.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSize(width: boss1.size.width, height: boss1.size.height))
    boss1.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.boss.rawValue
    boss1.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.ball.rawValue
    boss1.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.noCollision.rawValue
    boss1.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    boss1.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
    boss1.zPosition = 5
    self.addChild(boss1)

    boss1.runAction(SKAction.moveToX(self.frame.width / 2, duration: 1))

    let spawnBallsAction = SKAction.sequence([SKAction.waitForDuration(2), SKAction.runBlock(spawnBalls)])
    self.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(spawnBallsAction))

}

func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    let firstBody : SKPhysicsBody = contact.bodyA
    let secondBody : SKPhysicsBody = contact.bodyB

    if (firstBody.categoryBitMask & PhysicsCategory.bar.rawValue == PhysicsCategory.bar.rawValue &&
        secondBody.categoryBitMask & PhysicsCategory.ball.rawValue == PhysicsCategory.ball.rawValue) {

            CollisionWithBar(firstBody.node as! SKSpriteNode, ball: secondBody.node as! SKSpriteNode)

    }

    if (firstBody.categoryBitMask & PhysicsCategory.ball.rawValue == PhysicsCategory.ball.rawValue &&
        secondBody.categoryBitMask & PhysicsCategory.boss.rawValue == PhysicsCategory.boss.rawValue) {

            CollisionWithBoss(firstBody.node as! SKSpriteNode, boss: secondBody.node as! SKSpriteNode)

    }

}

func CollisionWithBar(bar: SKSpriteNode, ball: SKSpriteNode) {
    ball.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(0, 500))
    ball.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.boss.rawValue //Trying to solve the problem, aint working
}

func CollisionWithBoss(ball: SKSpriteNode, boss: SKSpriteNode) {
    NSLog("Ball hit the boss")
}


func spawnBalls(){

    let ball = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "ball.png")
    let MinValue = self.frame.width / 8
    let MaxValue = self.frame.width - 20
    let SpawnPoint = UInt32(MaxValue - MinValue)
    ball.position = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(SpawnPoint)), y: self.frame.height - 128)
    ball.zPosition = 50

    //Physics
    ball.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: ball.frame.height / 2)
    ball.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.ball.rawValue
    ball.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.bar.rawValue
    ball.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.noCollision.rawValue
    ball.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
    ball.physicsBody?.dynamic = true

    self.addChild(ball)
}
```

Comment: when you say add, do you mean ball.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.boss.rawValue | PhysicsCategory.whitebar.rawValue.  also, are they sharing the same categoryBitMask?  because they should not be sharing the same collisionBitMask,  you should have the collisionBitMask not look at boss on the start,  then when it hits the white paddle, activate it

Comment: Can you edit your post with the code that pertains to your problem? It will help to see how you are creating the 3 nodes and their physics bodies along with what happens when the ball first hits the white bar and the test you are doing to see if the ball is colliding with the boss.

Comment: @TrentSartain I added all the code. I'm also trying KnightOfDragons idea, comming back soon!

Comment: @Knight0fDragon If i do not use the same collisionBitMask on both ball & boss, the balls does not go through the boss? They get stuck and roll on the sides. Maybe i just dont understand your explanation, im sorry. I also added the code so you can check it out

Comment: OK you have a few issues to worry about here,  1 being that firstBody can either be bar or ball,  the order is not preserved, so you need to handle that, otherwise you may hit a condition where firstBody is ball and secondBody is bar, and nothing will happen

Comment: 2  Both ball and boss are set to noCollision  Is this value 0?  if so they will never collide and perform physics(if this is what you want of course)

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Can i add a thirdBody? I'm new to xcode and i'm kind of clueless right now... I really appreciate you trying to help me out

Comment: no,  there are many examples out there,  but basically you want to set firstBody to the category mask that is lower, and secondBody to the category mask that is upper

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Yes, ball & boss should never have any visible physics going on. I just want to know when the ball hits the boss on the way up, and (not) on the way down. I just want to check if the ball hits the boss, and then remove some health

Comment: well then you start the game with the ball ONLY allowed to contact the bar,  then when the bar and ball make contact, you say the ball can now collide with bar and boss,  then when the ball hits the boss, you say it can only collide with bar.  I will write the example in the answer for you

Comment: @Knight0fDragon That would be super sweet. I'm honestly still confused, i thought i already did what you suggested. Initially ball can only touch bar. They collide, ball can now only touch boss. But maybe i got some of the physicsBody."those" wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how contacts should be done:

Upon creating a ball set the contact category to this:(which you have)

```
ball.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.bar.rawValue
```

Make sure the boss contacts nobody:

```
boss1.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.noCollision.rawValue
```

Then on Contact, you want to do this:

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    let firstBody : SKPhysicsBody = (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask <= contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask) ? contact.bodyA : contact.bodyB
    let secondBody : SKPhysicsBody = (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask >= contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask) ? contact.bodyA : contact.bodyB

    if (firstBody.categoryBitMask & PhysicsCategory.bar.rawValue ==  PhysicsCategory.bar.rawValue &&
     secondBody.categoryBitMask & PhysicsCategory.ball.rawValue == PhysicsCategory.ball.rawValue) {
            //This should be inside CollisionWithBar
            ball.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.bar.rawValue | PhysicsCategory.boss.rawValue

            //the ball has hit the bar, so lets enable hitting on the boss
            //normally we would only want to do this once, but since this is 
            //tiny, it would be more time to wrap it in ifs and putting guards on it
            boss1.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.ball.rawValue
            CollisionWithBar(firstBody.node as! SKSpriteNode, ball: secondBody.node as! SKSpriteNode)

    }

    if (firstBody.categoryBitMask & PhysicsCategory.ball.rawValue == PhysicsCategory.ball.rawValue &&
    secondBody.categoryBitMask & PhysicsCategory.boss.rawValue == PhysicsCategory.boss.rawValue) {
            //This should be inside CollisionWithBoss
            ball.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.bar.rawValue

            CollisionWithBoss(firstBody.node as! SKSpriteNode, boss: secondBody.node as! SKSpriteNode)

    }

 }
```

Which basically says,  if the ball hits the bar,  enable boss hitting, if the ball hits the boss, disable boss hitting

Edit:  Upon the realization of having multiple balls,  we have to change some things

Make sure the boss contacts ball upon creation again:

```
boss1.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.ball.rawValue
```

Now we need to create a new category

```
enum PhysicsCategory : UInt32 {
    case bar = 1
    case ball = 2
    case boss = 4
    case noCollision = 8
    case initialBall = 16
}
```

In the beginning,  assign the category of ball to this:

```
ball.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = initialBall
```

Then your CollissionWithBar will look like this:

```
func CollisionWithBar(bar: SKSpriteNode, ball: SKSpriteNode) {
    ball.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(0, 500))
    ball.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.bar.rawValue | PhysicsCategory.boss.rawValue


    ball.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.ball.rawValue 
}
```

And your CollissionWithBolls will look like this:

```
func CollisionWithBoss(ball: SKSpriteNode, boss: SKSpriteNode) {
    ball.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.bar.rawValue
}
```

Finally, on Contact, you want to do this:

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    let firstBody : SKPhysicsBody = (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask <= contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask) ? contact.bodyA : contact.bodyB
    let secondBody : SKPhysicsBody = (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask >= contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask) ? contact.bodyA : contact.bodyB

    if (firstBody.categoryBitMask & PhysicsCategory.bar.rawValue ==  PhysicsCategory.bar.rawValue &&
     secondBody.categoryBitMask & PhysicsCategory.ball.rawValue == PhysicsCategory.ball.rawValue) {
            CollisionWithBar(firstBody.node as! SKSpriteNode, ball: secondBody.node as! SKSpriteNode)

    }

    if (firstBody.categoryBitMask & PhysicsCategory.ball.rawValue == PhysicsCategory.ball.rawValue &&
    secondBody.categoryBitMask & PhysicsCategory.boss.rawValue == PhysicsCategory.boss.rawValue) {


            CollisionWithBoss(firstBody.node as! SKSpriteNode, boss: secondBody.node as! SKSpriteNode)

    }

 }
```

Comment: I noticed that the CollisionWithBoss fires when the ball spawns as well. (While its going through the boss for the first time. Maybe i wasnt clear) But basically i want to remove health from the boss when they collide for the second time only, so that the boss doesnt lose health just by a ball spawning

Comment: I knew I forgot to do something in the answer,  I updated it

Comment: Edited to handle multiple balls